# Select only a single column in a HTML table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to select the text of a single column from the HTML table using mouse pointer.

For example consider the following table.

[image]

In this table, I cannot select the the text of **Lastname** column alone. Instead, the rest of the table contents are also selected while dragging the mouse down.

The ultimate aim is to select each column separately.Is there is any way to select the text of single column in the table?

Tried all different options the `-moz-user-select`, but nothing worked out.

Comment: Three tables, with a single column each ?

Comment: If its fixed number of columns its fine. But in my case, the columns number are dynamic and also I think its may not be a right approach.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want columns to be selectable, you have to provide that structure in the HTML. And that will involve using tables within tables, like this:
http://codepen.io/DavidvanDriessche/pen/jqbeqK

The basic approach is to make one outer table with a single row. This row has as many column (td) elements as required (while the example shows three, it can easily be adjusted to any number of columns you want/need.

These td elements contain their own table with nothing but rows (each row having a single column). Columns can now be selected individually.

```
<table><tr>

    <td>
      <table>
        <tr><th>First name</th></tr>
        <tr><td>David</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Frank</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Bob</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>

    <td>
      <table>
        <tr><th>Last name</th></tr>
        <tr><td>David</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Frank</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Bob</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>

    <td>
      <table>
        <tr><th>Third name</th></tr>
        <tr><td>David</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Frank</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Bob</td></tr>
      </table>
    </td>  

</tr></table>
```

Answer (score 5):

add a class to your last name and add this css properties.

Here is another way on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shohidulpaltan/9uzmeacp/).

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.unselectable {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -khtml-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 -o-user-select:none;
 user-select: none;
}
.selectable {
    -webkit-touch-callout: all;
 -webkit-user-select: all;
 -khtml-user-select: all;
 -moz-user-select: all;
 -ms-user-select: all;
 -o-user-select:all;
 user-select: all;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Add some css to lastname</h2>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <th class="unselectable">Firstname</th>
        <th class="selectable">Lastname</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="unselectable">Peter</td>
        <td class="selectable">Griffin</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="unselectable">Lois</td>
        <td class="selectable">Griffin</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Almost fine, but my problem is not about a single column, its about selecting each column values separately.  Adding "selectable" class to more than one column may not work. Close enough solution though and thanks.

Comment: This solution, combined with a bit of JS with a hover event, can make it possible to limit selection to whatever column you are hovering over.

Comment: This is a very old question and answer, but still one of the first hits on google when searching fo it.
So, to use this approach for the current column, some js is needed, as zeroimpl said. On mousedown inside a table, add the unselectable class to all columns but the current one, on mouseup remove it. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/yLkczspd/

Answer (score 1):

Gets the second column.

```css
table th:nth-child(2), table td:nth-child(2){
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>surname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Fred</td>
    <td>frankin</td>
    <td>mike</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Mike</td>
    <td>frankin</td>
    <td>jones</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

**EDIT with borders**

```css
th, td{
  padding: .2em .5em;
}
table { border: none; border-collapse: collapse; }
table th:nth-child(2), table td:nth-child(2) { border-left: 3px solid brown; }
table th:nth-child(2), table td:nth-child(2) { border-right: 3px solid brown; }
table th:nth-child(2) { border-top: 3px solid brown; }
table tr:nth-of-type(3) td:nth-of-type(2){border-bottom: 3px solid brown;}
table td:first-child { border-left: none; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>surname</th>
    <th>Another</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Greg</td>
    <td>Fred</td>
    <td>mike</td>
    <td>Another</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td >Sam</td>
    <td>Flinstone</td>
    <td>jones</td>
    <td>Another</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: Selecting Lastname column it also selects the other column values. Try selecting the contents of Lastname, Fred and Flinstone using mouse and you will notice it.

Answer (score 1):

I too needed to have selectable HTML columns.  The answer from @DavidvanDriessche put me on the right path but like @Naja2Raja, I needed a dynamic column solution.  I believe the following PHP code can lead you to a dynamic (unknown) column count solution.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="SELECT fName,email FROM Persons ORDER BY fname";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
    // Start an HTML table for each field
    $table0 = "<table id=\"table0\" name=\"table0\">
              <tr><th>Last Name</th></tr>
    ";

    $table1 = "<table id=\"table1\" name=\"table1\">
              <tr><th>Age</th></tr>
    ";

   // Fetch one and one row
   while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
   {
    $table0 .= "<tr><td>". $row[0] ."</td></tr>\n";
    $table1 .= "<tr><td>". $row[1] ."</td></tr>\n";
   }

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);

// Close HTML table
  $table0 .= "</table>";
  $table1 .= "</table>";

// Place HTML Column Tables into Single Row HTML table with a <td> 
// column for each HTML Column Table
echo "<table><tr>
        <td>
          $table0 
        </td>
        <td>
          $table1
        <td>
      </tr></table>";

}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For alignment purposes you can also have tables within tables,

Schematic only:

```
OuterTable(
           td(leftColumnTable)/td 
           td(midColumnTable)/td
           td(rightColumnTable)/td
           )
/OuterTable
```

This will allow highlighting of individual columns, as well as the complete table.

Comment: Sorry I am not aware of how to implement the above code?

Answer (score 0):

```
        <style>
    table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    }

    td, th, .ff-fix {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    }

    td:hover::after,
    .ff-fix:hover::after { 
    background-color: #ffa;
    content: '\00a0';  
    height: 10000px;    
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;  
    top: -5000px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;        
   }
   </style>
   <script>

    function tablefunhover() {

        var tds = document.getElementsByTagName( 'td' );

    for( var index = 0; index < tds.length; index++ ) {
        tds[index].innerHTML = '<div class="ff-fix">' + tds[index].innerHTML + '</div>';                     
    };

    var style = '<style>'
        + 'td { padding: 0 !important; }' 
        + 'td:hover::before, td:hover::after { background-color: transparent !important; }'
        + '</style>';
    document.head.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeEnd', style );

    };
    tablefunhover();


   </script>
    <table>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th><th>Lastname</th><th>Email</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>xyz</td><td>xyz</td><td>xyz</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>xyz</td><td>xyz</td><td>xyz</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>xyz</td><td>xyz</td><td>xyz</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>xyz</td><td>xyz</td><td>xyz</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
```

[ref](https://jsfiddle.net/2XeYe/584/)

Comment: My question is to select the text while dragging, the solution that you provide only does hover, but when I click and drag, still the other items gets selected.

Answer (score -2):

This question is old, but I didn't really like the other answers. They seem more complex than necessary. I simply assigned classes.

```css
.column2 {
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th class="column1">Firstname</th>
    <th class="column2">Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="column1">Greg</td>
    <td class="column2">Smith</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="column1">Sam</td>
    <td class="column2">Flinstone</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: You missed the point of the question from the OP. This is not about selecting a column in CSS, it's about using the mouse and doing a drag-select that only selects a particular column. That is not accomplished using the solution you present.